# Automatical repair of number of corrupted .xlsx files via VBA script

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of corrupted .xlsx files in a directory.
I want to open every single file for repair and save it with the same name via VBA script.

I`ve tried following piece of code to solve this problem:

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
Dim Filename, Pathname As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\output\"
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")
Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename, CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile)
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

But this code only repairs first file and opens windows explorer to save file manualy.

Is there a way to perform repair and save all files with the same name in the same folder automatically?

Comment: Folder loops are well documented here. Please browse for a few questions to see how to implement a `Dir()` loop

Comment: @urdearboy i know how to loop over Dir, this is just piece of code that is inside loop over the dir. As I said in my question the problem is that every file in the loop has to be saved manualy

Comment: @takeshi6 perhaps should post the entire code then and not leave us guessing :)

Comment: @Rawrplus edited question with entire code

Comment: Haven't touched VBA in years, but isn't there an explicit wb.Save method you can call?

Comment: @HardCode using method SaveAs with same Filename is wokring. Thank you very much for this idea. Can you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't touched VBA in years, but there is an explicit `wb.SaveAs` method you can call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `Application.DisplayAlert = False`? Your codes seems fine. You just have to turn it on later.

Comment: No, that doesn`t work. Window Explorer still pops up asking where to save repaired file

Comment: That’s weird. I replicated your code both with ‘SaveAs’ and without ‘SaveAs’ and it seems fine.

Comment: could you attach file which you`ve used?